# Issue with Laravel hasMany relation with condition whereIn

Tags: laravel

How to make relation with condition where in

```
function manyThings() {
    return hasMany('users','id','1,2,3,4');
}
```

How to make the above condition in proper eloquent relationship?

Comment: Please check again [`hasMany` in Laravel API](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method___construct)

Comment: If you ask people for help, why the help you won't even format your question?